# spring-boot-devtools doesn't reloads context Eclipse

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, pom.xml, spring-boot-devtools

pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency> 

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1207.jre7</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have referred following link:
[Spring Boot DevTools doesn't reaload the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550236/spring-boot-devtools-doesnt-reaload-the-application)

It still doesnot help!!!!
My context doesnot gets updated on refresh

My controller class

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    SchoolEducation_ServiceInterface servceintrfc;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome()
    {

        System.out.println("auto restarted");
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("index");
       return "Hello Changed World!!!!";
    }
```

I tried changing the prints!!!!It doesnot change.

I have also added the maven plugin.

Comment: Are you using intelliJ idea as your IDE? And how are you running you Spring boot application?

Comment: I'm using MyEclipse , and running application using command :spring-boot:run in maven build... goals

Comment: Try running your application from eclipse itself. `Right Click--> Run As --> Spring Boot App`